# how to draw rect on .obj rendered view in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I've rendered .obj file using libgdx. Now I've to draw squares on it with different color, so how could I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? Are you just trying to draw a square directly onto the screen, or around a 3D object, or what?

Comment: I just added image in a question. Same as this, I've to draw square on this rendered object with different colors.